# Keeping code separate - Swift Table View controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am using various tutorials to help me learn iOS development with Swift.

The issue I am having is understanding how to seperate out my code but still have the same result.

My example:

In the interface builder, I have a screen with a UITableView. 
I have connected that to a separate class called TableControllerClass:

```
class TableClass: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet var myTable: UITableView!

    var tableData:NSArray = NSArray()

    func setData(data:NSArray){

        self.tableData = data
                println("reloaded table")
                myTable?.reloadData()

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        myTable.delegate = self
        myTable.dataSource = self
        println("Hi there!")
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        println("holla")
        return tableData.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "myCell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello World"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Hello Again!"
        return cell

    }
```

Within the original *ViewController*, I call a method from a data retrieving class:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var search = ProfileSearch()
        search.getProfiles("helloWorld")
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "dataDownloaded:", name: "tableDataDownloaded", object: nil)
    }

    func dataDownloaded(notif:NSNotification){

        var data:NSArray = notif.object as NSArray
        println("changing table")
        tableController.setData(data)


    }
```

So far, so good. I get the results and Using my dataDownloaded method, I am able to send the data to the Table controller class.

The issue I am having is then updating the table based on this new data:
When I call reloadData() on my tableView, nothing seems to happen and my table simply stays empty.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: You don't use an IBOutlet to connect a tableView to a UITableViewController subclass - as it is a UITableViewController it's `view` property is the tableview. You probably just want a class that implements tableview data source and tableView delegate protocols rather than a UITableViewController subclass

Comment: Hmm okay - where would I setup the UITableViewController methods?
I understand it would be easier to just keep it all in one class but I would like to learn to separate my code early on

Comment: Have a read of the UITableViewController documentation. It is a UIViewController subclass that specifically supports a tableView as its view. You can use it if you don't have any other UI elements in your view, however if you do then you would normally just use a UIViewController subclass and have it implement the dataSource and delegate protocols. This viewController instance would then be assigned to the dataSource and delegate properties of the tableView in your scene. You can use a separate class as the dataSource and delegate in which case you would assign an instance of this to the props

Comment: okay so I want to use the UIViewController that i create the table in as the controller and then I can seperate the delegate/source code rather than all of it.

Comment: Yes, you can do that but in my experience it isn't particularly common to do so

Comment: In this situation, is there any performance gain in seperating my code out more?

Comment: No, in fact you will use more memory because you have to instantiate another object, however this won't have a significant impact. Often you have other UI elements as well as your tableView and changes in one might affect the other, so the complexity of passing messages between a separate delegate class and your view controller tends to outweigh any advantage from decoupling the dataSource/delegate from the view comtroller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70131/discussion-between-nmyster-and-paulw11).

Comment: Your help was great and I've now got it working. Can you add your comments as an answer and I'll approve it :)

Comment: I also want to separate my code, but how to set the datasource/delegate manually to a UiTableView, UiTableViewDelegate, UiTableViewDatasource heriting class?